# Is there a fast and efficient way of converting a React Native app into a React web app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was wondering if there is a way of doing this without actually going through the entire application and adapting it manually.

Comment: have not used it myself. but there is a popular one https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web.